# Google Sheets: Custom Number Formats feature seems buggy

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to use km/h or kmph as a unit but it results in displaying "k5/13". Am I doing something wrong or is this really a bug and if so, is there a workaround?

[image]

Comment: The reason you were having trouble is that some letters already have meaning in formatting. In your case, `m` means months, and 'h' means hours; so these will try to return a *number* indicating the month and the hour associated with the number you entered in the cell. For instance if your number entered in a cell was 122.54, this would show as 122.54 K5/13, because the `m` of day 122 from Sheets origin date of December 30,1899 would fall in May (month 5) and 0.54 of a 24-hour day falls at 1:00PM (hour 13).

Comment: Thank you Erik, that makes sense. So it's not a bug, it was just my ignorance.

Comment: We're all on a learning curve in life (at least if we're doing it right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a solution:

[image]

Thank you for your time a effort in trying to help me.